# Direct connection FIFO to Zynq ARM

Tags: xilinx, fifo, vivado, zynq

First of all I'm new in developing projects for FPGA WITH embedded ARM (or MicroBlaze) cores. My first project used transmitting a number of data to PS through FIFO. The main problem - I can't use DMA (it's blocked for other needs). As result I just connect few FIFO and Register to Zynq PS through AXI Interconnect. The main question: How I can read data from FIFO using xilinx SDK?

[Block Design picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp3jm.jpg)

Other question: is there any other options connect data to PS without DMA

Comment: The AXI FIFO generator basically generates a FIFO instance for all the signals in the AXI protocol. Something like a pipeline. It is not an addressable space. Is this what you need?

Comment: I understand that, but I need receive data from FIFO. No matter how, just read and use it in project. Like stream or variable etc. How can I do that by functions?

Comment: on zynq device you can use interlan dma of the ps or you can use different dma on the pl at the same time!!!!